# The Api-Platform ApiFilter does not show the filtered results

Tags: api-platform.com

I don't know how to use ApiFilters. If I use them, I will get all entries in my Result

....

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\DateFilter;

 #[ApiResource()]

 #[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: [ 'name' => 'partial'])]


curl -X 'GET' \
  'https://ANYDOMAIN/api/manufacturers?page=1&name=xxxx' \
  -H 'accept: application/ld+json'
```

What is missing?